# Equally spaced points on archimedian spiral

Tags: r

I know how to plot an archimedian spiral

```
a <- 20 #distance from origin
b <- 1 #distance between loops
maxtheta <- 20*pi  #10 times round the loop

theta <- seq(0,maxtheta,0.01) #my sequence of angles
r <- a + b*theta # equation for the spiral

df <- data.frame(x=r*cos(theta), y=r*sin(theta)) # convert points to Cartesian coordinates
#then plot them to get spiral
```

**In addition, I would also like to plot evenly distributed points on the spiral, but my points are always unequally spaced so far.**

Comment: What's wrong with `plot(df, pch=20, cex=.1, asp=1)`?

Comment: I belive that just plots the spiral, what I wish to do is add some extra points to it all with a constant spacing between them along the track of the spiral

Comment: I see, see my answer for an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could systematically select rows using modular math.

```
plot(df, pch=20, cex=.1, asp=1)
points(df[seq_len(nrow(df)) %% 50 == 0, ], pch=20, col='red')
```

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks, though I am not sure how to select rows in a way that would obtain an equal spacing of points around the whole spiral

Comment: @steve Playing around with the modulo I guess.